# Is there an equivalent to chmod 555 on Windows?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, file-permissions, .env

I'm trying to get the CompreFace Javascript SDK up and running and I'm running into this error.
I'm using a .env to store my API keys and using sholladay's envy module to read in values, but the program stops when I actually call the `envy()` function. This is the error I get:

```
Uncaught Error Error: File permissions are unsafe. Make them 555 '.env'
    at envy (file:///C:/Users/admin/Documents/node_modules/envy/index.js:95:15)
    at <anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/admin/Documents/js_src/face_biometrics.js:5:19)
    at run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
    --- await ---
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    --- await ---
    at runMainESM (node:internal/modules/run_main:60:21)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:5)
    at <anonymous> (node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)
Process exited with code 1
```

I tried setting the file to read-only but no luck. Here is my MRE:

```
import envy from "envy";

const KEYS = envy()
```

and my .env looks something like this:

```
RECOGNITION_KEY = 
VERIFICATION_KEY =
```

Comment: Instead of trying to make windows do something it can't do (nor something that shouldn't even be necessary), switch to [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv), as that's basically "_the_ way you load .env files" in Node land.

Comment: I used envy because I read it is basically an upgraded version of dotenv, but if it doesn't work for Windows then... 
Thank you for the tip.

Comment: @ndxw where did you read that? `envy` is a dead project. Always check the stats in npm before using a package.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command from `powershell` or `cmd` by specifying file path:

```
icacls "C:\path\to\your\file" /grant:r everyone:R,X
```

Comment: that's really not part of the solution for this problem.